# Google API Client Location

Tags: javascript, api, location

I want to detect the browser client location, so I wrote this code:

```
 if(google.loader.ClientLocation)
{
var visitor_lat = google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude; 
var visitor_lon = google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude; 
var visitor_city = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city;
var visitor_region = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region;
var visitor_country = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country;
var visitor_countrycode = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
document.getElementById('yourinfo').innerHTML = '<p>Lat/Lon: ' + visitor_lat + ' / ' + visitor_lon + '</p><p>Location: ' + visitor_city + ', ' + visitor_region + ', ' + visitor_country + ' (' + visitor_countrycode + ')</p>';
alert("Found Location");
}
else
{
// ClientLocation not found or not populated
// so perform error handling
alert("Could not find client location... ");
}
```

I have looked at many other web tutorials, and this code should work, but it doesn't for me :S.
Is it something about Google disabling ClientLocation function?

Comment: Perhaps you can make a fiddle of this? http://jsfiddle.net/
I have found that this code works from some locations and not others. That is, I can get my country code from my home pc not my work pc. Try testing in other locations.